# Problem with my program-it returns nothing

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program which takes 5 random characters from 'tab' list, and appends them to other list (t1). Next step is to compare t1 list to "won" list (this list contains lucky characters). If t1 is equal to won program should returns lucky characters (t1) and sum of all attempts (p),but of course it doesnt work. Could you help me?

```
tab=['a','e','x','t','b','3','536','2','5','6','79','5634','2','234','0']
win=['a','x','3','79','b']
t1=[]
active=True
p=0
while active:
    for i in range(5):
        wygrana=choice(tab)
        t1.append(wygrana)
    win.sort()
    t1.sort()
    if win==t1:
        p+=1
        print(f"You WON!! You needed {p} attempts, and your lucky characters are {t1}")
        active=False
    else:
        p+=1
```

Comment: This is a great opportunity for `pdb`! `python -m pdb myscript.py` .. use `?` for commands, `b` to set a breakpoint (wants a 1-index line number as the argument) and `c` and `n` to continue to the next breakpoint or go to the next line. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: You keep on appending to `t1` forever.  Only on the very first iteration of the `while` loop is there any chance of it being equal to `win` - on subsequent iterations, it's too long to be equal.  You need to clear `t1` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [User:jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper) after every iteration clear `t1` as you are using `append` method which will keep on adding Element at back at after Single iteration its size become more than `5` which makes condition always `False`.
**Make these change in you code:**

```
...
while active:
    for i in range(5):
...
```

**to**

```
...
while active:
    t1 = []
    for i in range(5):
...
```

### Method-2

Create `t1-list` using this way where each iteration `t1` get recreated automatically :

```
...
while active:
    t1 = [choice(tab) for _ in range(5)]
    win.sort()
    t1.sort()
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now everything is clear for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You never clear the `t1` list. You can simplify everything and avoid this problem as below. It works by only appending to the list comprehension if the choice is in `win`. If the final list is the same length as `win` then it must have all the proper elements.

You don't need to `sort` anything using this method, and a bunch of your variables become unnecessary.

```py
from random import choice

tab=['a','e','x','t','b','3','536','2','5','6','79','5634','2','234','0']
win=['a','x','3','79','b']

p=1
while len([i for i in range(5) if choice(tab) in win]) < 5:
    p+=1
    
print(f"You WON!! You needed {p} attempts, and your lucky characters are \"{' '.join(win)}\"")
```

If you wanted to make it a lot more dynamic you could do something like this

```py
from random import choice, randint

tab=[chr(i+(randint(0, 1)*32)) for i in range(65, 91)]
win=[choice(tab) for _ in range(5)]

p=1
while len([_ for _ in range(5) if choice(tab) in win]) < 5:
    p+=1
    
print(f"You WON!! You needed {p} attempts, and your lucky characters are \"{' '.join(win)}\"")
```